# Cómo compilar correctamente Vite + React js?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, vite, jsx

Al ejecutar `npm run build` me compila solo lo que está dentro de **public**, y tengo entendido que el producto final es lo que se encuentra dentro de la carpeta **dist**.

Por lo que a la hora de correr el programa y cargar los componentes, no los encuentra, ya que estos se encuentran en **src**.

El proyecto cuenta con un **Login** el cual se puede visualizar, y puedo iniciar sesión ya que al ser válidas las credenciales se renderiza otro componente pero la url no cambia. Y a la hora de cargar dinámicamente (con lazy) los demás componentes, el proyecto lanza el siguiente error mediante la consola:

```
GET http://localhost:4173/src/pages/remu_pages/Home.jsx net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Será que me falta alguna configuración extra? O el orden de las carpetas no sea el correcto?

También cabe mencionar que al ejecutar el proyecto con `npm run dev` funciona todo correctamente.

Mi archivo **vite.config.js** es el siguiente:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: '',
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '/assets/': '/public/assets/',
      '/contexts/': '/src/contexts/',
      '/components/': '/src/components/',
      '/pages/': '/src/pages/',
    },
  },
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
    assetsDir: 'assets',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: './index.html', 
      },
    },
  },
});
```

El orden de las carpetas es el siguiente:

```
- proyecto/
  - dist/ ...
  - node_modules/
  - public/
    - assets/ ...
  - src/
    - components/ ...
    - contexts/ ...
    - hooks/ ...
    - pages/ ...
    - main.jsx
  - package.json
  - resto de archivos ...
```